# how to make bash to recognize character ranges when doing regex match?

Tags: regex, bash

Bash 4.3.33 i've noticed this behavior. Looks like regex engine doesn't recognize `[]` as meta characters. Is there any way to enable full (extended? or how is this called) regex support ?

```
var=bananas
if [[ "$var" =~ "[as]"$ ]]; then
  echo 'yes'
else
  echo 'no'
fi
if [[ "$var" =~ "s"$ ]]; then
  echo 'yes'
else
  echo 'no'
fi
var=bananas]
if [[ "$var" =~ "]"$ ]]; then
  echo 'yes'
else
  echo 'no'
fi
```

output:

```
no
yes
yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use double quotes in the regex part.

```
if [[ "$var" =~ [as]$ ]]; then
```

So,

```
var='bananas'
if [[ "$var" =~ [as]$ ]]; then
  echo 'yes'
else
  echo 'no'
fi
if [[ "$var" =~ s$ ]]; then
  echo 'yes'
else
  echo 'no'
fi
var='bananas]'
if [[ "$var" =~ ]$ ]]; then
  echo 'yes'
else
  echo 'no'
fi
```

will produce,

```
yes
yes
yes
```

Comment: Better said: You *cannot* use quotes. Or rather, when you quote a regex metacharacter, it becomes a normal character.